# Grub_rescue error : unknown filesystem , error loading operating system

Tags: boot, grub2

I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed in my system.
I removed Ubuntu and installed it again. When I restarted the system, it showed:

```
Error : Unknown filesystem 
grub rescue >
```

When I use the `ls` command I am getting this

```
(hd0),(hd0,msdos8),(hd0,msdos7)(hd0,msdos6)(hd0,msdos5)
(hd0,msdos4)(hd0,msdos3)(hd0,msdos2)(hd0,msdos1)
```

But when I run `ls (hd0)/` it's saying `unknown partition`. The same case for all the others `(hd0,msdos1)` to `(hd0,msdos8)`.

I tried booting a new OS from USB, and I am getting

```
Error loading operating system
```

I also tried Super Grub from USB, but I still get the same error `Error loading operating system`.

Please let me know what to do now.

Comment: Which software did you are used to make bootable super grub usb?

Comment: Try reinstalling GRUB from the LiveCD as a first step in troubleshooting check whether that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from an Ubuntu live CD
2. Mount the partition. Create a new folder in your media folder. `sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu`. Then simple mount your partition to that folder. `sudo mount /dev/sdxx /media/ubuntu`
3. Run these commands

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /media/ubuntu/dev
   sudo mount --bind /sys /media/ubuntu/sys
   sudo mount --bind /proc /media/ubuntu/proc
   ```
4. Change the root directory to the one on your ubuntu partition.

   ```
   sudo chroot /media/ubuntu/
   ```
5. Install grub2 again:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sdx
   ```

   NB: replace `sdx` with the correct drive name